# How to act usercontrol as a childwindow in silverlight mvvm?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

Is there any possible way to act usercontrol as a childwindow..?
 I need usercontrol will be act like childwindow... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can put Usercontrol Inside Content of Childwindow.
it possible in mvvm too.

```
System.Windows.Controls.ChildWindow childWindow = new System.Windows.Controls.ChildWindow();
childWindow.Content = userControlObject; 
childWindow.Show();
```